# Logic operations OR, AND, and NOT

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

One of Kanchana, Damitha, Ranjan, Roshan or Pooja broke a vase. The following is what each of them had to tell about the person who broke the vase- only one of these statements is false and others are true.

1)Kanchana- Damitha broke it
2)Damitha- Kanchana lied
3)Ranjan- I did not break it
4)Roshan- I did not break it
5)Pooja- Ranjan or Kanchana broke it.

Who broke the vase??

Comment: Pooja and Damitha both say that Kanchana lies. The statements cannot both be false, so...Now you know which statement is false and the rest is easy.

Comment: The names are so nice! I wish no one broke  it.

Comment: Hey @drhab : Only Damitha says that Kanchan lies. Pooja does not say so. In the same manner, take a look at those first two statements, both of them can not be true simultaneously. Is not it?

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, stay tuned with me, and I will hope to present the whole accurate answer later..

Comment: If the statement of Pooja is true then the statement of Kanchana must be false. So *indirectly* Pooja says that Kanchana lies. You find the same reasoning in the answer of @OGC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damitha said that Kanchan broke the vase and Pooja said that either Ranjan or Kanchan broke it, so both statements are true as there are no contradictions.

No contradictions from Ranjan and Roshan saying that they didn't break the vase.

The only inconsistency is that Kanchan saying that Damitha broke the vase. Because Damitha said that Kanchan lied and Pooja thinks Kanchan broke it. So the statement made by Kanchan is false and Kanchan is the one who broke the vase.

Comment: Hey @OGC, I think you got the correct answer, and your logic is quite impressive. Thank you  very much for answering, stay tuned with me, and I will hope to present the whole accurate answer later..

Comment: @MaleeshRathnasiri No problem. Please feel free to upvote or accept my answer if you have found it useful. Thanks